# json array not displaying the values

Tags: php, json

I have the following json array, I am trying to retrive the values but it does not work

```
 => Array (
    [url] => http://chrome.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
    [title] => <b>Google</b> Chrome <b>Blog</b>
```

This is the code I am using in php to retrive the values

`$json = json_decode($res, true);`

`echo $json['url'];`

Can some one help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Its any array of arrays

```
echo $json[0]['url'];
```

From the comment

```
Array ( [responseData] =>
            Array ( [query] => Official Google Blogs 
                              [entries] => Array ( [0]=>


 echo $json['responseData']['entries'][0]['url'];
```

To display all the values you have to loop through each entries

```
foreach($json['responseData']['entries'] as $data)
{
  echo $data['url'];
}
```

Comment: I tryed this also but it gives following error PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/manoj/php/curl.php on line 10

Comment: You can't be certain that the index is actually 0, it could be a different integer, or it could be a string key.

Comment: This is the json I have Array
(
    [responseData] => Array
        (
            [query] => Official Google Blogs
            [entries] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [url] => http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
                            [title] => <b>Official Blog</b>
                            [contentSnippet] => 4 days ago <b>...</b> <b>Official</b> weblog, with news of new products, events and glimpses of life inside <br>
<b>Google</b>.

Comment: echo $json['responseData']['entries'][0]['url'];

Comment: This does not work, it gave the following error PHP Notice:  Undefined index: entries in /home/manoj/php/curl.php on line 11

Comment: But, how do i display all the values at once, like it will display only one value with the above line, but json file have many arrays, each array has one value

Answer (score 0):

Please debug the `$json`  via `print_r($json);` and then check current status of array and their indexes.